# I installed ubuntu 16.04 and now my wifi will not come up

Tags: wireless, system-installation, 16.04

After install 16.04, my wifi stopped working.  It recognizes it in Network Connections window, including my SSID and password.  It just wont connect.  Any suggestions?

```
*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 05
       serial: 08:9e:01:4c:37:0e
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw ip=192.168.0.110 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:28 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:90004000-90004fff memory:90000000-90003fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:90100000-90103fff
```